# How to increment the year in dropdown box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

As I am having very less knowledge in JavaScript cant figure out the solution.
I am trying to increment the year in drop down list whenever year changes using JavaScript

I have tried this below code.

```
function increment()
{
    var temp=document.getElementById("reviewYear_ID");
    var d = new Date();
    var len = temp.options.length;
    if(temp[len-1].value!=d.getFullYear())
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        var year =   d.getFullYear();
        opt.value=year;
        opt.text=year;
        temp.add(opt,len);
    }
}
```

JSP code :

```
<s:select list="#{'2012':'2012'}" headerKey="-11" 
    cssStyle="font-style: arial;font-size: 13px;"
    headerValue="--Select the Year--" name="reviewYear" id="reviewYear_ID"
    theme="simple"  >
  </s:select>
```

whenever year changes its adding the year to the dropdown but its actually replacing the previous year in that drop down list

for example .. in drop down list we have `2012` only assume this year as `2013` according to my code whenever jan 1 of 2013 comes it will add 2013 to the drop down. I have changed year in my local system to `2014` and tried this code 
   its adding `2014` but replacing the previously added `2013`  i want to that append to that drop down value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding right you want to add a option for each year from the last year in the select box to the current year. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JzsPt/4/) does just that. Try this code in place of your current increment function:

```
function increment(){
  var temp=document.getElementById("reviewYear_ID");
  var d = new Date();
  var len = temp.options.length;
  var start = temp[len-1].value;
  for(var i=parseInt(start); i < d.getFullYear(); i++){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    var year = i+1;
    opt.value=year;
    opt.text=year;
    temp.add(opt,len);
  }
}
```

Here we are adding each year until we get to the current year. Of course it may just be better to fix your JSP code to use something like `list="#{'2012':'2014'}"`. I am not sure how to do that because I don't know what JSP is but that isn't what you are asking anyways.

Comment: @looser I removed all of those pointless comments. Now that we have a final correct solution and the comments provide no real information they can be removed to prevent confusion from future viewers. You can do the same if you would like. And you are very welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: If you dont mind one more thing .. How to sort those years .. ?

Comment: They are added in an incremented order. They will be sorted already. If you want to change them to list from current date to oldest date you have to do a little more. Post that in another question if you can't figure it out. It is it's own question really.

Comment: They are not sorted  .. they are like `2012,2014,2013` and if one more year added `2012,2015,2014,2013` its been like this .. I need either `2012,2013,2014,2015` or `2015,2014,2013,2012` like this ..

Comment: @looser check the fiddle. Change `d.getFullYear()` to any date and it will work just fine. If it isn't doing this in your code then you changed something up. For instance http://jsfiddle.net/JzsPt/5/ shows to the year 2017 and I moved it to onload like you have it.